# Spreadsheet - ordering a column twice, using different scores (from 2 other colums)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am working on a spreadsheet - currently google docs but happy to see answers relating to other spreadsheet software.

I have a list of foods (column A - Food)
I have list1 of "scores" (column B - Score1)
I have list2 of "scores" (column C - Score2)

I would like to add two new columns, ideally ordering the food from column A according to the scores, both list1 and list2 - so one new column ordering the foods based on the score1 from column B, and the other new columns based on the score2 from column C.

An example usually helps, so here is what I have:

```
Food   Score1  Score2  
a          12      45      
b          96      67      
c         100      32
```

Now, this would be "Version 1", on the way to getting what I would like:

```
Food  Score1  Score2  Order1  Order2
a         12      45       3       2
b         96      67       2       1
c        100      32       1       3
```

Or, even better, "Version 2" - use the food name in the new columns, in the right order according to scores:

```
Food   Score1  Score2  FoodScore1  FoodScore2
a         12       45         c           b
b         96       67         b           a
c        100       32         a           c
```

I suspect that getting "Version 1" is probably achievable (but don't know how to do it)
I suspect that getting "Version 2" is not possible without some sort of procedural programming?

Hope someone can help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or, even better, "Version 2" - use the food name in the new columns, in the right order according to scores:

Let `A2:A10` - is your food range, `B2:B10` - score1 range, `D2:D10` - destination range ( `FoodScore1` in your example)

Works both in **EXCEL** and in **GOOGLE-SPREADSHEETS:**

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$10,1+ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)),$B$2:$B$10,0))
```

enter this formula in `D2` and drag it down

---

**If formula will give you an error, try to change `,` to `;` (depends on your local settings).**

**P.s.** for `score2` formula would be the same, just change ranges from `score1` to `score2` (i.e. `$B$2:$B$10` to `$C$2:$C$10`)

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks so much! Tested in google spreadsheets and it works a treat. Now I need to reverse engineer a bit and learn how you did that :)

Comment: Glad it helps you:) if you have some qestions, ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a rank column, with number 1 for the highest score, number 2 for the second highest, etc.

In Microsoft Excel, assuming that the first column is `A` and that all the scores are unique, you could simply have a formula like

```
=COUNT.IF(B:B, ">=" & $B1)
```

in column `D1`, and similarly in column `E` for the second score.

Then if you fill column `F` with the ranks 1, 2, 3, ... you can simply do a `VLOOKUP`. Or, in this case, an equivalent solution with `INDEX` and `MATCH` - because you want to lookup the rank in column `F` and return the corresponding value from column `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I need to go through this one

Comment: That's a typo, isn't: `COUNT.IF`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in a Google Spreadsheet, one would expect to see some Googliness in the solutions provided. Use this very simple, only usable in Google Spreadsheet, formula.

### Formula

```
// FoodScore1
=QUERY(B2:D4, "SELECT B ORDER BY C DESC")

// FoodScore2
=QUERY(B2:D4, "SELECT B ORDER BY D DESC")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The data range of the `QUERY` function is simply `B2:D4`. Then a quasi SELECT statement is made to select only column B and ordered by column C or D, descendingly.

### Reference

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage